# Grails, storing app own settings (singleton domain class?)

Tags: grails, configuration, grails-orm

I'm developing an app using [Grails](http://grails.org/) and there are some app-wide configuration settings I'd like to store somewhere. The only way I've thought of is to create a domain class that stores the configuration values, and to use a service that queries that domain class. The problem I see is that there should be just one instance of that domain class, but I haven't found anything to enforce that restriction.

There may be other best practices to store app's own configuration that I may not be aware of, all suggestions are welcome.

Edit: the settings are supposed to be configurable from within the app.

Comment: assuming that you actually want to store this info in the database, a domain class is fine. I'm not sure that there's any utility in going to any great lengths to enforce the singleton - just create an attribute on which you can query (findByXXXX), and use a constant for the value of that attribute. Pre-populate the database with the one row, and don't have any code that ever creates it in the app - just query and update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a plugin for that: [Settings](http://grails.org/plugin/settings).  It allows you to create named setting like `my.own.x` of different types (String, date, BigDecimal and integer), and provides you with the basic CRUD pages to manage them.

You can access the settings from either gsp:

```
<g:setting valueFor="my.own.x" default="50" encodeAs="HTML"/>
```

or controllers/services/domains

```
Setting.valueFor("my.own.x", 50)
```

I use it in several projects and think it works great.

Answer (score 7):

There is special place: `/grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`. You can add values there like:

```
my.own.x=1
```

and read values by:

```
def x = grailsApplication.config.my.own.x
```

See docs for more details: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#config

Comment: That's cool, but I forgot to mention that those parameters are supposed to be configurable from within the app.

Comment: You can store it in your `environment` block, if it's just environment specific. Or else in database, if it's should be modified by site admin, or something.

Answer (score 2):

You can enforce your single domain class db entry via custom validator:

```
// No more than one entry in DB
class MasterAccount {
    boolean singleEntry = true
    static constraints = {
         singleEntry nullable: false, validator: { val, obj ->
              if(val && obj.id != getMasterAccount()?.id && MasterAccount.count > 0){
                    return "Master account already exists in database"
              }
         }
    }
    MasterAccount static getMasterAccount(){
         MasterAccount.list()?.first()
    }
}
```

You can defer its configuration and persistence to `Bootstrap.groovy`, which would achieve the same effect as `Config.groovy`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 1.3.* you can try grails dynamic-config plugin (http://www.grails.org/plugin/dynamic-config).  "This plugin gives your application the ability to change the config properties without restarting the application. The values in Config.groovy are persisted in database when application is run-for the first time after installing the plugin. "

I've never used it on a grails 2.0.* project.